# Jquery stickfooter issue

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, sticky-footer

I have managed to figure out; how to stick footer at the bottom of document : i.e. when document < than viewport I call position:absolute in jquery otherwise relative which works fine along with css however when I re-size the browser it mess up the positing and if document size > viewport, the footer overflow with document.

I am using ASP.net with MVC 4 in visual studio 2012

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="header">
            my header
        </div>

        <div id="body">
                    @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
                    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                        @RenderBody()
                    </section>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            my footer
        </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).bind('load', function () {
//$(document).ready(function(){
    var doc_height = $(document).height();
    var viewport_height = $(window).height();

    if (doc_height > viewport_height) {
        $("#footer").css({ position: "relative" });
    }
    else {
        $("#footer").css({ position: "absolute" });
    }

    alert("doc " + doc_height + " viewport " + viewport_height);
});
```

```
html, body 
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%; }

 #container {
 min-height:100%;
 position:relative;}

 #header {
 background:#ff0;
 padding:10px;}

 #body {
 padding:10px;
 padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
 background-color:red;}

 #footer {   
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
 background:#6cf;
 margin-bottom: 0;}

 #container {
 height:100%;}
```

Comment: i just found is issue with IE browser.. any solution

Comment: Are you looking for something like this (pure css)? http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: @Per Salbark i have just figure out with jquery ... i hope is best option... unless you know something better that is pure css ??? thanks

Comment: Yeah, the link I posted is a Sticky Footer. Works in all browsers and no JavaScript. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the same function to `$(window).resize()` as well as `$(document).ready()` / `$(window).load()`:

```
//$(document).ready(resizeHandler);
$(window).load(resizeHandler).resize(resizeHandler);

var resizeHandler = function() {
    var doc_height = $(document).height();
    var viewport_height = $(window).height();

    if (doc_height > viewport_height) {
        $("#footer").css({ position: "relative" });
    }
    else {
        $("#footer").css({ position: "absolute" });
    }

    //alert("doc " + doc_height + " viewport " + viewport_height);
};
```

Comment: the code breaks with doc_height < viewport_height and footer movies up in middle of document

Comment: when i run with above code where doc_height < viewport_heigh, the footer moves up in the middle of document instead of staying at bottom, however i was playing around with code and is fixed. here is following